# Django MultiValueKeyDictError while saving data for a multistep form

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class multi_form(View):
    model=Customer
    template_name='index.html'

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'customer/index.html')

    def post(self,request):
        if(request.method!="POST"):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(''))
        else:
            first_name=request.POST.get("fname")
            last_name=request.POST.get("lname")
            personal_email=request.POST.get("Pid")
            official_email=request.POST.get("Oid")
            current_address=request.POST.get("Cadd")
            permanent_address=request.POST.get("Padd")
            pan_card_number=request.POST.get("Pan")
            aadhar_card_number=request.POST.get("Aadhar")
            loan_amount=request.POST.get("LAmount")
            request.session['fname']=first_name
            request.session['lname']=last_name
            request.session['Pid']=personal_email
            request.session['Oid']=official_email
            request.session['Cadd']=current_address
            request.session['Padd']=permanent_address
            request.session['Pan']=pan_card_number
            request.session['Aadhar']=aadhar_card_number
            request.session['Lamount']=loan_amount
            personal_photo=request.FILES['PhotoAttachment']
            bank_statement=request.FILES['BankAttachment']
            salary_slip=request.FILES['SalaryAttachment']
            pan_card=request.FILES['PanAttachment']
            aadhar_card=request.FILES['AadharAttachment']
            try:
                CustomerForm1=CustomerInfo(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, personal_email= personal_email, official_email=official_email, current_address=current_address, permanent_address=permanent_address, pan_card_number=pan_card_number, aadhar_card_number=aadhar_card_number, loan_amount=loan_amount)
                CustomerForm2=Customer(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, personal_email= personal_email, official_email=official_email, current_address=current_address, permanent_address=permanent_address, pan_card_number=pan_card_number, aadhar_card_number=aadhar_card_number, loan_amount=loan_amount, personal_photo=personal_photo, bank_statement=bank_statement, salary_slip=salary_slip, pan_card=pan_card, aadhar_card=aadhar_card)
                CustomerForm1.save()
                CustomerForm2.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your Response has been recorded")
                return render(request, 'customer/index.html')
            except:
                return render(request, 'customer/index.html')
```

So, I was trying to save fields of a multi-step form. Upon submission after only the first step and skipping the second step altogether I am displayed this error.

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /
('PhotoAttachment', None)
```

How do I resolve this and save data of first of this form ie. CustomerForm1. I want to save data in form fields of both the forms although they contain duplicate fields

Note: If I remove the submit button in first step and CustomerForm1 from views.py then I don't get this error implying forms works fine otherwise.

Comment: It means `request.FILES` does not contain the `PhotoAttachment` key (and likely is completely empty).

Comment: Can it not be empty then since I haven't made the file upload fields necessary fields?

Comment: yes, for example because the `enctype=...` in the form is not specified. Nevertheless it is not a good idea to such validation yourself. This is one of the many reasons why Django forms are useful, even if you do not render these, you can make more robust validation.

Comment: Then what would be a better way to achieve the storage in database of fields of first form by using this method only? For now I don't want to do it by using forms.py file.

Comment: you don't need any `forms.py`, you can define the form where you want, so in the `views.py`. But anyway. A simple browser extensions, or a forged request can simply break the view. One can make a POST request where any key/value pair is missing, has the wrong format, etc. This is exactly what forms are used for.

Comment: So can any of my file fields not be none while submission then by the method I'm using? Or is there a way round it?